# PHP curl post to login to wordpress

Tags: php, curl

I followed [Wordpress autologin using CURL or fsockopen in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724107) to login to wordpress, using php_curl, and it works fine as far I use WAMP, (apache/php).

But when it comes to IIS on the dedicated server, it returns nothing.

I have wrote the following function which is working fine on my local wamp, but when deployed to client's dedicated windows server 2k3, it doesn't. Please help me

```
function post_url($url, array $query_string)
    {
        //$url = http://myhost.com/wptc/sys/wp/wp-login.php
        /*      $query_string = array(
                            'log'=>'admin',
                            'pwd'=>'test',
                            'redirect_to'=>'http://google.com',
                            'wp-submit'=>'Log%20In',
                            'testcookie'=>1
                        );
        */

        //temp_dir is defined as folder = path/to/a/folder
        $cookie= temp_dir."cookie.txt";


        $c = curl_init($url);



        if (count($query_string))
        {
            curl_setopt ($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
                http_build_query( $query_string )
            );

        }

        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
        //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //return the content
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
        //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
        //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, wp_admin_url);
        //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10); 

        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CRLF, 1);


        try {
            $result = curl_exec($c);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $result = 'error';
        }

        curl_close ($c);

        return $result;  //it return nothing (empty)
    }
```

## Other Facts

1. curl_error($c); return nothing
2. when header CURLOPT_HEADER is set to ON,
   it return this header

HTTP/1.1 200
    OK Cache-Control: no-cache,
    must-revalidate, max-age=0 Pragma:
    no-cache Content-Type: text/html;
    charset=UTF-8 Expires: Wed, 11 Jan
    1984 05:00:00 GMT Last-Modified:
    Thu, 06 May 2010 21:06:30 GMT
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.13 Set-Cookie:
    wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check;
    path=/wptc/sys/wp/ Set-Cookie:
    wordpress_b13661ceb5c3eba8b42d383be885d372=admin%7C1273352790%7C7d8ddfb6b1c0875c37c1805ab98f1e7b;
    path=/wptc/sys/wp/wp-content/plugins;
    httponly Set-Cookie: wordpress_b13661ceb5c3eba8b42d383be885d372=admin%7C1273352790%7C7d8ddfb6b1c0875c37c1805ab98f1e7b;
    path=/wptc/sys/wp/wp-admin; httponly
    Set-Cookie:
    wordpress_logged_in_b13661ceb5c3eba8b42d383be885d372=admin%7C1273352790%7Cb90825fb4a7d5da9b5dc4d99b4e06049;
    path=/wptc/sys/wp/; httponly
    Refresh:
    0;url=http://myhost.com/wptc/sys/wp/wp-admin/
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Thu, 06
    May 2010 21:06:30 GMT
    Content-Length: 0

3. CURL version info:
   Array ( [version_number] => 463872 [age] => 3 [features] => 2717 [ssl_version_number] => 0 [version] => 7.20.0 [host] => i386-pc-win32 [ssl_version] => OpenSSL/0.9.8k [libz_version] => 1.2.3 [protocols] => Array ( [0] => dict [1] => file [2] => ftp [3] => ftps [4] => http [5] => https [6] => imap [7] => imaps [8] => ldap [9] => pop3 [10] => pop3s [11] => rtsp [12] => smtp [13] => smtps [14] => telnet [15] => tftp ) )

   4. PHP Version 5.2.13
   5. Windows Server 2K3
   6. IIS 7
   7. Working fine on Apache, PHP 3.0 on my localhost (windows)

Answer (score 0):

Quick thought: Check to make sure that temp_dir."cookie.txt" is writable by IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it myself, it was some small fix in the wordpress rather than any IIS or PHP specific information.

I have modified wp_redirect() (just commented major part) in the following part to fix it

```
function wp_redirect($location, $status = 302) {
    global $is_IIS;

    $location = apply_filters('wp_redirect', $location, $status);
    $status = apply_filters('wp_redirect_status', $status, $location);

    if ( !$location ) // allows the wp_redirect filter to cancel a redirect
        return false;

    $location = wp_sanitize_redirect($location);

    /*
    if ( $is_IIS ) {
        status_header($status);
        header("Refresh: 0;url=$location");
    } else {
        if ( php_sapi_name() != 'cgi-fcgi' ) {
            status_header($status); // This causes problems on IIS and some FastCGI setups

        }
        header("Location: $location", true, $status);
    }
    */
    header("Location: $location", true, $status);
}
```