# PHP curl post to login to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I am using php curl to login to wordpress behind-the-scenes as described here:
[Wordpress autologin using CURL or fsockopen in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724107)

However my script is not setting the cookies necessary to retain the wordpress session.  Instead they are being sent back to my script and stored in cookies.txt.

Both the curl script and the wordpress login are on the same server in different directories.

Do I need to write another curl script to manually set the wordpress cookies?  Is that possible?

Comment: You should probably show some code.

Comment: Can we see this script, more than likely your not setting up a cookie file /' cookie jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using the code posted as is then it won't work because the subsequent requests won't send the cookies back on each request. Adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);` should help (well, at least it will if the cookies actually get saved now - otherwise look into permissions) - well, depending on what your usage scenario is anyway.

You could also check out [10 awesome things to do with cURL](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-awesome-things-to-do-with-curl) for some neat examples on how to use curl (example 4 might just be what you are looking for).

BTW If this script is intended for multiple (concurrent) users, you shouldn't use a static filename, but create a temporary file for each user.

Comment: I needed the cookies to be sent to the browser not back to my curl script.  The curl script was triggered by a php script running in the browser.  I solved the problem as follows:

Answer (score 0):

I needed the cookies to be sent to the browser not back to my curl script.  The curl script was triggered by a php script running in the browser.

I solved the problem as follows:

1. Added these params to the curl object:

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER ,1);
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'read_header');
2. Added a php functions called read_header which parsed out the cookie data
3. Used setcookie() to manually set the cookies

**If anyone wants the details please comment.**