# global login between CMS multisite

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, magento

I have a website that uses 3 different CMS's. Wordpress CMS, Magento CMS, and Vbulliten CMS. I'm curious as if it's possible to create a single global login solution on the homepage that allows logging in / registering once, that carries over to all of the CMS's. I understand this is a large task. Curious about a suggested approach to this. I have setup a social login with facebook for each portion. But I am curious an approach that is non social login.

Comment: This would be a better question for Programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: should be able to find existing bridges between several of those. Binding them all together would probably require some customization of a bridge

Comment: @jwatts1980 this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat I get the "is it possible to" thing, and had the OP stopped there, I would agree. However, he stated that he DOES have a SSO-like solution involving Facebook, so he's clearly done some legwork there... this is not just a shot in the dark. To me this is clearly not a code question, but more of a "software architecture and design" question. And besides that, this OP has an established rep on SO, seems like the kind of user you would want to encourage to be active on Programmers. (@mattdamon sorry about 3rd person references, trying to understand gnat's logic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a pixel to load a login cURL/fsock script for each CMS. That would address any cross-domain cookie issues.

```
<img src="HTTP://PATH-TO-LOGIN-SCRIPT-FOR-WordPress.php">
<img src="HTTP://PATH-TO-LOGIN-SCRIPT-FOR-Magento.php">
<img src="HTTP://PATH-TO-LOGIN-SCRIPT-FOR-vBulletin.php">
```

Here is a related post to auto-logging into wordpress.

[Wordpress autologin using CURL or fsockopen in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724107/wordpress-autologin-using-curl-or-fsockopen-in-php)

Then you could get creative an invoke a new browser tab via javascript.

I have never tested this, however It doesn't seem impossible! Good luck.

Comment: Yes, but that seems pretty similar to just hyperlinking to the 3 separate CMS login points. Thus which will be still logging in 3 different times..